# MS Project saves to 2007 format, option to change is grayed out

Tags: office365, file-extension, microsoft-project

I've got a user who has MS Project.

This user noticed his file opened in compatibility mode.  The file was saved in the 2007 format.

I went into project settings >> save >> save files in this format.  It's indeed set to "Project 2007" instead of "Project."  However, it's grayed out.  It cannot be altered.

I'm at a loss as to why/how his current version of Project would force him to the older format.

Answer (score 0):

The registry key that seems to control the
[default save format](https://admx.help/?Category=Office2016&Policy=proj16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_PjFileType)
is at the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\ms project\options\save`.

The item name is `defaultsaveformat` and its
[default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.optionssave)
are "MSProject.mpp", "MSProject.mpt", "MSProject.mpp12", or
"MSProject.mpp9".

Check what this person's value is of this key.
I believe the Project 365 value is `MSProject.mpp`.

Save the old value before changing it and try to start Project after
the change is done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I wound up finding the solution and posted it below.  I can’t thank you enough for posting your reply to the conundrum I had!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was a configuration profile forcing the .mpp format.

With the setting in place, and although there's no differentiation in the setting, the desktop app would lock the 2007 format in.

By removing the configuration profile that set the .mpp format, I was able to unlock the dropdown and choose the newer format.